# Thread 1 : SIGABRT error in simple storyboard app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have made an extremely simple app using Storyboards (for the first time).

The app's basically a Table View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller and that segues out to a View Controller which displays an image. But when I click on an row, it gives me a Thread 1 SIGABRT error. Here's the log :

2013-09-03 22:37:16.669 FootballPlayers[7226:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "PcV-xW-t12-view-xx8-ac-4rU" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c94012 0x10d1e7e 0x1c93deb 0x245357 0xf6ff8 0xf7232 0xf74da 0x10e8e5 0x10e9cb 0x10ec76 0x10ed71 0x10f89b 0x10fe93 0xc4823f7 0x10fa88 0x46be63 0x45db99 0x45dc14 0xc5249 0xc54ed 0xacf5b3 0x1c53376 0x1c52e06 0x1c3aa82 0x1c39f44 0x1c39e1b 0x1bee7e3 0x1bee668 0x15ffc 0x226d 0x2195 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Here's the implementation of the TableViewController

```
#import "PlayersTableViewController.h"

@interface PlayersTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayersTableViewController

NSMutableArray *players;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DisplayViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *path = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [dvc setCurrentPlayer:[players objectAtIndex:[path row]]];

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Player *stevenGerrard = [[Player alloc] init];
    [stevenGerrard setName:@"Steven Gerrard"];
    [stevenGerrard setFileName:@"Steven Gerrard.jpg"];
    [stevenGerrard setInformation:@"International Team : England, Club : Liverpool FC"];
    [players addObject:stevenGerrard];

    Player *cristianoRonaldo = [[Player alloc] init];
    [cristianoRonaldo setName:@"Cristiano Ronaldo"];
    [cristianoRonaldo setFileName:@"Cristiano Ronaldo.jpg"];
    [cristianoRonaldo setInformation:@"International Team : Portugal, Club : Real Madrid"];
    [players addObject:cristianoRonaldo];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [players count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PlayerCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    Player *current = [players objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[current name]];

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

What's wrong ?!

Thank You.

Comment: Do you segue from the individual prototype cell, or from the tableView itself?

Comment: I'm segueing from individual table cell

Comment: If you Ctrl+clicked from the prototype cell to the next VC and created a segue, either push or modal, then you should not be having that error.

Comment: @CaptJak - Its fixed now. By mistake, the ViewController I was segueing to was created as a TableViewController. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One very handy thing to do is to add an **Exception Breakpoint**: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

This way you'll probably see the exact place in your code where it goes wrong.

If the error occurs *after* tapping on a row, the code of the destination view controller is also interesting.

Comment: Yes, that's where the error is coming. It occurs after tapping on a row.

Comment: I never know about this feature. I wish I could +100 this suggestion. Than you.

Answer (score 0):

Your nib file is incorrectly constructed, most likely.

It would appear that you have something other than a table view connected to the table view controller's outlet that should point to the table view.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I have put the order in the story board wrong ? Because I checked that and its not the case. The view controllers are hooked up to the correct custom classes. The segues are correctly put. Tell me if you need more code for reference.

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag What is your table view controller's `tableView` property connected to?

Comment: I haven't edited the tableView property. Just dragged on a Table View Controller, attached a custom class to it. Tell me if you need more code. I can show you the destination ViewController's files also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are subclassing UITableViewController and not UIViewController (or anything else) in your .h file.

So it should look like:

```
@interface PlayersTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

Comment: Yes, its exactly like that.